# Moving wordpress from self-hosted into wp hosted

Tags: wordpress

I was using self-hosted wordpress for a while and now I want to move all posts, settings to my wordpress.com account. I mean I want create free wordpress hosted account and move all data from self-hosted account into it. Is that possible? if yes, how? please explain

Comment: Why?  People usually move the other way.

Comment: @PeterWooster My blog being attacked. Hackers attach some file to my cPanel and it ddos attacks another website. And Hosting company blocks my website nearly everyday. I can't solve this problem. The only way is to move blog into wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the usual direction to move, WordPress has documented it here: http://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-a-blog/

Answer (score 0):

Megatron, I've seen a few of your posts about this hack. Its an up-to-date Wordpress install with very few plugins. By the sounds of things (and I may well be wrong here), I doubt you have done a huge amount of customisation yourself which could have introduced a vulnerability.

It could well be your theme but frankly my money is on your hosts themselves. Wordpress is so prolific that when a hosting company running many shared servers gets hacked there are inevitably loads of Wordpress sites that get compromised as a result and Wordpress gets the blame. The hosting company certainly don't own up to it.

Before you go to .com, switch hosts. Clean install, plenty of guides out there on resurrecting a Wordpress site - you've said yourself on other threads the site is only a week old so it'll be very easy to do. My 2p.